# Error thread 1 exc bad access code 2 with MRCountrypickerlibrary

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,MRCountryPickerDelegate {


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


     countryPicker.countryPickerDelegate = self
     countryPicker.showPhoneNumbers = true
     countryPicker.setCountry("SI")
 }
```

Error occured on : `countryPicker.countryPickerDelegate = self`

I have tried to solve but can't get it... and gives me this error:

> thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-2-

I am using [MRCountrypickerlibrary](https://github.com/xtrinch/MRCountryPicker).

class implementation code:

```
open class MRCountryPicker: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var countries: [Country]!
open weak var countryPickerDelegate: MRCountryPickerDelegate?
open var showPhoneNumbers: Bool = true

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    countries = countryNamesByCode()

    super.dataSource = self
    super.delegate = self
}

// MARK: - Country Methods

open func setCountry(_ code: String) {
    var row = 0
    for index in 0..<countries.count {
        if countries[index].code == code {
            row = index
            break
        }
    }

    self.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    ****let country = countries[row]****
    if let countryPickerDelegate = countryPickerDelegate {
        countryPickerDelegate.countryPhoneCodePicker(self, didSelectCountryWithName: country.name!, countryCode: country.code!, phoneCode: country.phoneCode!, flag: country.flag!)
    }
```

updated code is above and it is the definition of MRCountryPicker

and here is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myapp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myapp
    pod 'MRCountryPicker'
end
```

Comment: did you comfort countryPhoneCodePicker function of your delegate?

Comment: yes and its like... func countryPhoneCodePicker(_ picker: MRCountryPicker, didSelectCountryWithName name: String, countryCode: String, phoneCode: String, flag: UIImage)
    {
        self.countryName.text = name
        self.countryCode.text = countryCode
        self.phoneCode.text = phoneCode
        self.countryFlag.image = flag
    }

Comment: no compilation error.. but when the application luanch it crashes and generate this erro

Comment: Can we get more code? Definition of your countryPicker maybe.

Comment: Varibales decllararion :               IBOutlet weak var countryPicker: MRCountryPicker!
    
    
    IBOutlet weak var phoneCode: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var countryCode: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var countryName: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var countryFlag: UIImageView!
    
MRPIcker code is download from library..Github

Comment: i am stuck.... didi u got the prob... and its as it is as github said....

Comment: I reproduced the error. Did you get the error 'Unknown class MRCountryPicker in Interface Builder file.' at the console? If so you should share that too.

Comment: Please show how/where you instantiate `countryPicker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you init your picker in storyboard you will see custom class section at identitiy inspector. You have to set both class and module to MRCountryPicker. Otherwise you will get the error.

Comment: one thing more.. that i did'nt use cocoapods ora anyother dependency manager.. just copy and paste from library to my project

Comment: can  u plz guide me how to check error in console as i am also new to swift

Comment: Ok. Which file did you copied to your project?

Comment: i copied the whole folder of MRCountryPicker...including all sub folder

Comment: just remove these files. Install it using cocoapods. Just make sure that your pod line is only "pod 'MRCountryPicker'" not with the version. If you include version it does not install somehow.